# Manage dependencies in a Play Framework app

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, playframework

I'm trying to figure out the proper tools for managing dependencies between JARs. I have a Play Framework app, which imports a JAR (based on another project I'm writing). This JAR imports other JARs, some of which have dependencies for yet *other* JARs.

This far, I've gotten by with adding stuff to the build path in Eclipse. But when I deploy the Play app (export to .war, deploy on Glassfish), the necessary JARs are not included. I need to *manually copy* these into play/lib. Which is a pain since they are so many.

So my question is two-fold:

- For the JAR file I'm writing: what's a better way of managing the dependencies? Maven?
- For the Play app, is there some way of avoiding copying stuff into /play/lib, and still be able to deploy without pain?

**In the ideal scenario, I would like to import a completely self-contained JAR-file into the Play app, i.e. I don't need to add the JAR-file's dependencies to play as well. How can I achieve this?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the easiest way to achieve what you want:
http://www.playframework.org/modules/ivy
(and you can combine it with IvyDE, an Eclipse plugin for managing dependecies with Ivy)

Comment: ivy comes with  cost .. can you suggest any of its alternative live maven or gradle

Answer (score 0):

you may try asking in the google list, they are usually very responsive...

http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework